# Javascript widget on page: This page is accessing information not under its control

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I am using a Javascript widget (specifically Accuweather) on my aspx page and it detects it as a call to another domain.

The Javascript widget is present on most of the site as it is in the master page.

It is showing me the error "**This page is accessing information not under its control" and can get annoying for some users**.

This happens on the Intranet Zone of our site.

I know one way to solve it is by changing the "**Access data sources across domains**" to **Enable** instead of *Prompt*. However, we have other sites that we don't want to be affected by the change. Changing the Intranet Zone affects all of the Intranet Sites.

Another possible way is, instead of being in the Intranet Zone, transfer it to **Trusted Sites** (which is configured properly already). However, our setup is to **automatically detect the Intranet Zone**. How can we do this?

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: I have seen this same issue with using the Yammer Widget embedded in a page.